# Proper URL for new york time API

Tags: json, api, android-studio

I am trying to build an android application using api key from this site [New York times](http://developer.nytimes.com/). But I am new on this type of applications (Using APIs) and i would like to know if the url that I am using is correct because i don't get any result when i execute the application and i am wondering if the api key is on the correct position.

Here is my url:

URL url = new URL( "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=big&opening-date=1930-01-01;2000-01-01&api-key=");

Comment: To define whether URL is correct just open it in the browser adding your actual api-key. Currently I can see {"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}. What is the response in your case? If you got expected result then URL is correct.

Comment: @vich Tnx! I find a mistake on my URL i fix it! I still have problem to get the information. But at least i know that is not the url!